# Is there any Bhakti as we understand it today in the "Bhakti Yoga" chapter of the Gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, bhakti

like the Bhakti of Mirabai for Krishna.

or, like Swami Sivananda put it:

"Bhakti is the slender thread of Prem or love that binds the heart of a devotee with the lotus feet of the Lord. Bhakti is intense devotion and supreme attachment to God. Bhakti is supreme love for God. It is the spontaneous outpouring of Prem towards the Beloved. It is pure, unselfish, divine love or Suddha Prem. It is love for love's sake. There is not a bit of bargaining or expectation of anything here. This higher feeling is indescribable in words. It has to be sincerely experienced by the devotee."

also see

[What is the Navavidha Bhakti?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7295/what-is-the-navavidha-bhakti?rq=1)

If Bhakti is different from Bhakti Yoga - an answer would say yea or nay - whether there is Bhakti in the Bhakti Yoga chapter.

Comment: Dude, your questions need to be more clear. I think you hastily write them. Please take your time.

Comment: I'm unable to understand, what exactly you might be asking in here sir. Maybe you would like to elaborate your doubt properly and perhaps in a bit more detail? Otherwise, the question seems very obscure to me atleast.

Comment: just read the chapter.  does it evoke Radha,or Mira or Tuka Ram?  seems too lacking in emotion to me. @vivikta

Comment: I'm still unable to grasp what do you really want to enquire or conjecture about. The question needs better focus and explanation.

Comment: I am done explaining @vivikta

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one differentiate between Bhakti and Bhakti Yoga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9808/how-does-one-differentiate-between-bhakti-and-bhakti-yoga)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/12

> But those who dedicate all their actions to Me, regarding Me as the Supreme goal, worshiping Me and meditating on Me with exclusive devotion, O Parth, I swiftly deliver them from the ocean of birth and death, for their consciousness is united with Me.
> Bhagavad Gita 12.8

> Fix your mind on Me alone and surrender your intellect to Me. There upon, you will always live in Me. Of this, there is no doubt.
> Bhagavad Gita 12.9

> If you are unable to fix your mind steadily on Me, O Arjun, then practice remembering Me with devotion while constantly restraining the mind from worldly affairs.
> Bhagavad Gita 12.10

> If you cannot practice remembering Me with devotion, then just try to work for Me. Thus performing devotional service to Me, you shall achieve the stage of perfection.
> Bhagavad Gita 12.11

> If you are unable to even work for Me in devotion, then try to renounce the fruits of your actions and be situated in the self.
> Bhagavad Gita 12.12

> Better than mechanical practice is knowledge; better than knowledge is meditation. Better than meditation is renunciation of the fruits of actions, for peace immediately follows such renunciation.
> Bhagavad Gita 12.13 – 12.14

> Those devotees are very dear to Me who are free from malice toward all living beings, who are friendly, and compassionate. They are free from attachment to possessions and egotism, equipoised in happiness and distress, and ever-forgiving. They are ever-contented, steadily united with Me in devotion, self-controlled, firm in conviction, and dedicated to Me in mind and intellect.
> Bhagavad Gita 12.15

> Those who are not a source of annoyance to anyone and who in turn are not agitated by anyone, who are equal in pleasure and pain, and free from fear and anxiety, such devotees of Mine are very dear to Me.
> Bhagavad Gita 12.16

> Those who are indifferent to worldly gain, externally and internally pure, skillful, without cares, untroubled, and free from selfishness in all undertakings, such devotees of Mine are very dear to Me.
> Bhagavad Gita 12.17

> Those who neither rejoice in mundane pleasures nor despair in worldly sorrows, who neither lament for any loss nor hanker for any gain, who renounce both good and evil deeds, such persons who are full of devotion are very dear to Me.
> Bhagavad Gita 12.18 – 12.19

> Those, who are alike to friend and foe, equipoised in honor and dishonor, cold and heat, joy and sorrow, and are free from all unfavorable association; those who take praise and reproach alike, who are given to silent contemplation, content with what comes their way, without attachment to the place of residence, whose intellect is firmly fixed in Me, and who are full of devotion to Me, such persons are very dear to Me.
> Bhagavad Gita 12.20

> Those who honor this nectar of wisdom declared here, have faith in Me, and are devoted and intent on Me as the supreme goal, they are exceedingly dear to Me.

Here is unmistakable Bhakti and there is nothing like that in the Bhakti Yoga chapter.:

> दर्शन दो घनश्याम नाथ मोरी अखियां प्यासी रे
> दर्शन दो घनश्याम नाथ मोरी अखिया प्यासी रे
> दर्शन दो घनश्याम
> मंन मंदिर की ज्योति जगादो
> मंन मंदिर की ज्योति जगादो
> घट घट बासी रे, दर्शन दो घनश्याम
> मंदिर मंदिर मूरत तेरी
> फिर भी ना दिखे सूरत तेरी
> मंदिर मंदिर मूरत तेरी
> फिर भी ना दिखे सूरत तेरी
> युग बीते ना आई मिलन की
> पूर्णमासी रे
> दर्शन दो घनश्याम
> द्वार दया का जब तू खोले
> पंचम सुर में गूगा बोले
> द्वार दया का जब तू खोले
> पंचम सुर में गूगा बोले
> अँधा देखे लंगड़ा चल कर
> पहुँचे कासी रे
> दर्शन दो घनश्याम
> पानी पी कर प्यास बुझाओ
> नैनन को कैसे समझाऊँ
> आँख मिचौली छोड़ो अब तो
> मंन के बासी रे
> दर्शन दो घनश्याम नाथ मोरी
> अखिया प्यासी रे
> दर्शन दो घनश्याम

> O Krishna! Bless us with your presence, our eyes are thirsty for the sight of you.
> Light up the temple of our hearts, O dweller of every soul.

> Lord! Every temple has your idol,
> Even then I haven't seen you.
> The age has come to an end, and yet
> the time for seeing you hasn't arrived

> O Krishna! when you open the gates of your grace,
> even the dumb sing in mellifluous voices,
> The blind see and even the one-legged walk to Kashi to offer obeisance.

> Lord! I drink water to quench my thirst,
> but how what do I tell my eyes which crave for you?
> O Krishna! O Dweller of my heart! Please end these blindfolded games and appear before me.